# Call bash function in IRB

Tags: ruby, bash

If I run a custom bash function under shell console:

```
~/w/dotfiles/ruby [g:master-] ¶ repository_root
/Users/tian/Documents/workspace/dotfiles
```

And if I run the custom bash function under IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> `repository_root`
(irb):1: command not found: repository_root
=> ""
```

How could I get the same result in IRB?

```
# declare
repository_root () {
    if git_is_repository ; then
        git_show_repository_root
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function is in one of your bash profile files, you want to start up an interactive (`-i`) login (`-l`) shell to execute (`-c`) your function:

```
output = %x{bash -lic 'repository_root'}
```

Comment: Don't know why it's not running at the first time. Actually this is a better way to go.

Comment: Works for me w/o any issues. I'll get down to study the -lic switches now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make a command out of the function.

Here's a short how-to

1. Create a shell script file that calls the function.
2. Create a `.bin` directory in your `HOME` and add it to `$PATH` in `.bash_rc`.
3. Place the shell script file in `.bin`.
4. `source .bash_rc` to update the `$PATH` variable you just changed.
5. Assuming you named the file `fnx`, just use the back tick operator or `exec` to run 
   the command - `exec("fnx")`

Answer (score 0):

where is `repository_root` declared?

.bash_profile? .bashrc?

try to source that file before using `repository_root`

```
`. /path/to/file/declaring/repository_root; repository_root`
```

Comment: it works, but is there better way not required to source the file?